# Implementing Swipe In My Image Gallery (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

what i want to do is that  i have a nice image Gallery which is currently working on Next and Previous Links to go back and forward.
i want to do the same when ever user **swipe** that is just like iPhone etc (touch Mobiles).
i am implementing it on my website  for PC's not for mobiles.swipe in sense of mouse not thumb
how to catch these Events???
Any Idea will be ll help full

Comment: do you need to listen to these events in case of mobile access to the page? if so, use jquery-mobile's swipe listeners

Comment: @Th0rndike no i need to implement it on my website on pc not for mobiles.swipe insense of mouse not tumb.hope you got what i am trying to say

Comment: actually, jquery mobile swipe events work in a normal browser as well. That is, of course, if you're willing to attach the jquery-mobile library to your site just for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do something similar for jquery draggable items.

Check out http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/ it makes all jquery-ui elements work on iPhone and iPad :)